# Manifolds and Polynomials

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, polynomials

Given a compact smooth manifold $M \subset R^k$ there is a Polynom $f\in R[x_1,..x_n]$ such that the zero set of $f$ is diffeomorphic to $M$. Can the coefficients of $f$ be pertubated slightly to a Polynomial $g \in Q[x_1,..x_n]$ such that the zero set of $g$ is diffeotopic to $M$? Are their conditions on the homology or homotopy on $M$ such that such a pertubation process is possible / not possible? What happens if Q is replaced by an arbitrary number field K?

Comment: Why is there a polynomial whose zero set is diffeomorphic to $M?$ there is a real algebraic variety homeomorphic to it, but that's not the same as what you say. The variety might only be one connected component of a zero set of a polynomial...

Comment: Hi,
as far as I know thats the tognoli part of the nash tognoli theorem?
Please correct me if i am wrong. A proof can be found in Bochnak Coste Roy (or Akbulut and King)

(To get a single polynom from a finite set of polynoms you could sum the squares of the polynoms, (they are real))

Comment: I think there is even  better Nash theorem that would allow isometric, for a given Embedding, but the distortion is then so weird

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: proven in Ballico, E., Tognoli, A., *Algebraic models deﬁned over $\mathbb{Q}$ of diﬀerential manifolds.* **Geom. Dedicata** 42 (1992), no. 2, 155–161. In fact, you can get the zero set to be diffeomorphic to $M$, not just diffeotopic.

Comment: Don't you even need orientability?

Comment: No, you don't, apparently.

Comment: this does imply that there are only contable compact smooth diffeomorphism types. Can this be seen in a more elementary style?

Comment: @Markus:  There are various proofs, and I believe there's already an MO thread on that topic but a quick search did not turn it up.  One would be to argue that every triangulated manifold has only finitely many smoothings.  In dimensions $n \geq 5$ I believe this is a standard theorem in Kirby-Siebenmann smoothing theory.  I think you can make a much simpler arguments using the technique Whitehead used to prove all smooth manifolds admit triangulations. 

Comment: @Markus: It follows for example from Cheeger's finiteness theorem (there are only finitely many diff-types of manifolds which admit complete metric with |curvature| $\le 1$ and diameter $\le D$).

Comment: One might read Ryan and Anton as saying "No, this is the most elementary proof."

Comment: Chester funkendes Theorem seems to Be more elementaty, since nö cobordism is Meeres, only riemannian geometry. 


Comment: Who is Chester? Do you mean Cheeger? Which proof uses cobordism?